# In python,I want to use join function but i am getting an error:"TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, join, methods

*#Declared a string**

```
s=','

#I want to apply join method of string

print(s.join['cats','rats','bats'])
```

I want the desired output->cats,rats,bats
but instead of this i am getting an error which stated above

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis for the call `s.join(['cats','rats','bats'])`. Because for now you apply the brackets to the method itself, and this notation is trying to subscrite it, like `mylist[5]` or `mystring[0:5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis and specify the list inside it.

```
s=','

print(s.join(['cats','rats','bats']))
#Output cats,rats,bats
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the function parentheses there. This leads to the error since square brackets are also used as the subscript operator (e.g. when accessing an element of a list).
Fill your join method with the list, like this: `s.join(['cats','rats','bats'])`